# How to remove the tag <h>

Tags: php

How to remove the `<h2>` tag or change it to `<div>`

I tried this:

```
$str= '<h2 class="widgettitle"> Cart </h2>';
$new_string = strip_tags($str);
```

Source text

```
<h2 class = "widgettitle"> Cart </ h2>
```

Need to change to

```
<div class = "widgettitle"> Cart </ div>
```

I need code that I can write in functions.php

Comment: You must remove whole string

Comment: Please post your code using CTRL + K to see your soruce...

Comment: Your code is working for me: https://3v4l.org/OQ5UJ